# DOS Batch file - Copy file based on filename into default folder

Tags: batch-file, dos, filenames, special-folders

I would like to use a batch file to put them into default folder, but the account name is in the middle of the folder. Have any script I can use in dos command prompt?

```
888123_AAAA_20130313.pdf  
888123_BBBB_20130313 (2).pdf  
888123_CCCC_20130313_2.pdf  
777456_AAAA_20130313.pdf  
777456_BBBB_20130313 (2).pdf  
777456_CCCC_20130313_2.pdf
```

Default folder:

```
999-888123-03
666-777456-01
```

Comment: what do your mean? which file to which folder?

Comment: where do you want to put what? Please explain.

Comment: Are these all .pdf files? Do they always start with a 5 digit number? Are they all in the same directory? Where is the default folder in relation to the files? Please clarify your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create the list of default folders
set folder[888123]=999-888123-03
set folder[777456]=666-777456-01

rem Copy the files
for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D *.pdf') do (
    copy "%%a_%%b" "!folder[%%a]!"
)
```

**EDIT**: The version below don't need to initialize the list of default folders:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D *.pdf') do (
   for /D %%d in (*_%%a_*) do (
      copy "%%a_%%b" "%%d"
   )
)
```

Comment: If _all folders_ are located in the same drive (different than file's drive), just insert it in the willd-card (name) of target folder. If each target folder may be located in a different drive, use the first version with full folder names.